# Python-social-auth get user city

Tags: django, python-social-auth

I'm trying to get (and save) the user city or location using django and python-social-auth. It will be loaded on the first time the user logging, so I created a PIPELINE

```
  """
SOCIAL AUTH
"""
SOCIAL_AUTH_PIPELINE = (
    ...
    'libs.util.associate_by_email',
    'libs.util.load_data_new_user',
     ...
)
SOCIAL_AUTH_FACEBOOK_KEY = "...."
SOCIAL_AUTH_FACEBOOK_SECRET = "...."
SOCIAL_AUTH_FACEBOOK_SCOPE = [
    'email',
]
```

And the pipeline are looking like this:

```
def load_data_new_user(backend, response, user, *args, **kwargs):
print kwargs['details']
if user is None:
    if backend.name == "facebook":
        try:
            url = "http://graph.facebook.com/%s/picture?width=200&height=200&redirect=false" % response['id']
            data = json.loads(urllib2.urlopen(url).read())['data']
            print data
            return {'avatar': data}
        except StandardError:
            return {'avatar': None}
    else:
        raise ValueError()
```

It's working to get the avatar, but how can I catch the user city?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Add the `user_location` scope to the `SOCIAL_AUTH_FACEBOOK_SCOPE` setting
2. Get the location by doing `response['location']` in a pipeline (users that didn't fill their location in their profile won't have that key, so check for it first)

Comment: user_location was exatcly what I'm looking for. Thank you very much, its a honour receive a message coming from you. Congrats for this great job.

Comment: How can I do the same for "events"? I want to get the user_events, so I put it using SOCIAL_AUTH_FACEBOOK_SCOPE = [
    'email',
    'user_location',
    'user_events'
] and it worked for Facebook, but doesn't worked to receive events on response[].

Comment: You need to call the corresponding API for that, the scope only grants you access to that particular endpoint, check the docs at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.2/user/events.